# Alexa Skill - Is possible to get what user said?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm using lambda to create the skill, the same logic in hello world example. Is possible to get what user said? In Text?

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler =  {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'HelloWorldIntentHandler';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
  const speechText = 'Hello World!';

return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechText)
        //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
        .getResponse();  

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexa does not provide the full user input in text. So the only way to get what the user says is to use slots. Read about how to use **[Intents with Slots here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-the-interaction-model-for-your-skill.html#intents-and-slots)**.

Here are the different types of slots (`slotTypes`) that you can use to help Alexa extract the values you want from the user input. **[List of Slot Types](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#list-slot-types)**.

If you don't know the specific type of data you want to get from the user, then you could use the slot type `AMAZON.SearchQuery` to capture phrases and sentences.

Then it should deliver at least more of the user input (as Alexa understood it) into that slot as text.

**[AMAZON.SearchQuery](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery)**

> As you think about what users are likely to ask, consider using a built-in or custom slot type to capture user input that is more predictable, and the AMAZON.SearchQuery slot type to capture less-predictable input that makes up the search query.